# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы сайт открывался в большем масштабе?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня относительно небольшой сайт, для проекта, который дали в шараге, и дабы скрыть пустые и незаполненные бока, я хотел бы, чтобы сайт открывался как при масштабе 125%, но при этом браузер бы показывал стоковые значения(100%). Может быть не ясно выразился, но как-то так.
И еще один вопрос: почему при увеличении ширины меню, футера и т.п - он не увеличивается в ширину пропорционально, а увеличивается в право.
Буду благодарен хоть одному ответу на вопрос.(ниже приведен CSS,изза которого при расширении "иконок" у меня все смещается вправо)

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5em; 
    background-color: #0c2436;
    background-image: url(../images/tooplate_wrapper.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top center;
}

a, a:link, a:visited { 
    color: #0c2437; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.orange {
    color: #C60;
}

.green {
    color: #399;
}

p { margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 0; }
img { border: none; }
blockquote { font-style: italic; margin: 0 0 0 10px;}
cite { font-weight: bold; color:#375c06; }
cite span { color: #666; }
em { color: #000; font-weight: 400 }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: #000; font-weight: normal;  }
h1 { font-size: 34px; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 5px 0 }
h2 { font-size: 28px; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 5px 0 10px 0; color: #fff }
h3 { font-size: 20px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; margin: 0 0 15px; padding: 0; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0;  }
h6 { font-size: 14px; margin: 0 0 5px; padding: 0; }

.cleaner { clear: both }
.h10 { height: 10px }
.h20 { height: 20px }
.h30 { height: 30px }
.h40 { height: 40px }
.h50 { height: 50px }
.h60 { height: 60px }

.float_l { float: left }
.float_r { float: right }

.image_wrapper { 
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 4px; 
    background: #fff; 
}

.image_fl { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 3px 20px 0 0; 
}

.image_fr { 
    float: right; 
    margin: 3px 0 0 20px; 
}

.tooplate_list { 
    margin: 20px 0 20px 10px; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
}

.tooplate_list li { 
    color:#375c06; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 0 5px 15px; 
    background: url(../images/tooplate_list.png) no-repeat scroll 0 4px;  
}

.tooplate_list li a { 
    color: #375c06; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

.tooplate_list li a:hover { 
    color: #375c06; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

#tooplate_body_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background:  url(../images/tooplate_body.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}

#tooplate_wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:  url(../images/tooplate_body.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}

#tooplate_header {
    width: 858px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 40px 20px 10px;
}

#site_title { 
    float: left; 
}

#site_title h1 { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

#site_title h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 195px; 
    height: 46px; 
    background: url(../images/tooplate_logo.png)  no-repeat top left; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    outline: none; 
    text-indent: -10000px; 
}

/* menu */

#tooplate_menu { 
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 10px; 
}

#tooplate_menu ul { 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
}

#tooplate_menu ul li { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline-block; 
}

#tooplate_menu ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 105px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 29px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;    
    margin-left: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
}

#tooplate_menu ul li a:hover, #tooplate_menu ul .current {
    color: #000;
    background: url(../images/tooplate_menu_hover.png) no-repeat center center;
}

/* end of menu */

#tooplate_main {
    clear: both;
    width: 800px;
}

.content_box { 
    clear: both; 
    width: 800px; 
}

.content_title { 
    width: 700px; 
    height: 30px; 
    padding: 15px 50px; 
}

.content_ct {  width:100%;
    background: url(../images/tooplate_ct.png) round; 
}

.content { 
width:100%;
    padding: 30px 50px ; 
    background: url(../images/tooplate_content.png) round; 
}

.content_bottom { 
    width: 800px; 
    height: 49px; 
    padding-top: 20px;  
}

.content_cbf { width:100%;
    background: url(../images/tooplate_gototop_bgl.png) round; 
}

.content_cb { width:112.5%;
    background: url(../images/tooplate_gototop_bg.png) round; 
}

a.gototop { 
    display: block; 
    width: 108px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}

a.gototop:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

.col_w340 { width: 340px }

.post_box { 
    width: 320px; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;  
}

.post_header { 
    border-top: 3px solid #999; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.post_box h3 { 
    font-size: 24px; 
    line-height: 34px; 
    margin-bottom: 15px; 
}

.post_box img { 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 15px; 
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px; 
    padding-bottom: 11px; 
    background: url(../images/tooplate_post_img_bg.jpg) no-repeat; 
}

.post_box p.post_meta { 
    font-size: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0; 
}

#gallery { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}

#gallery ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#gallery ul li { 
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 168px; 
    margin: 0 15px 30px 15px; 
}

#gallery ul img { 
    z-index: 1000; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 150px; 
}

#gallery ul span {  
    position: absolute; 
    border: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 168px; 
    background: url(../images/tooplate_image_bg.jpg) no-repeat; 
}

#contact_form { 
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px; 
}

#contact_form form { 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}

#contact_form form .input_field { 
    width: 240px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    color: #666; 
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;  
    background: #fff; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}

#contact_form form label { 
    display: block; 
    width: 100px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    font-size: 13px; 
}

#contact_form form textarea { 
    width: 288px; 
    height: 150px; 
    padding: 5px; 
    color: #666; 
    border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;  
    background: #fff; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}

#contact_form form .submit_btn { 
    background: #559402; 
    color: #fff; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    border: 1px solid #3d6b00; 
    padding: 2px 5px; 
}

#tooplate_footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 20px 4px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#tooplate_footer a { color: #fff }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Андреев В.В.</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<link href="css/tooplate_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.localscroll-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.localScroll();
    $('#map a').lightBox();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<span id="top"></span>
<div id="tooplate_body_wrapper">
<div id="tooplate_wrapper">
    <div id="tooplate_header">
        <div id="site_title">

        </div>
        <div id='cssmenu'> <!-- МЕНЮ! -->
<link href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <ul>
     <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Главная</a></li>
     <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Проекты</a>
        <ul>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Компьютерная графика</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href=rastr.html>Растровая графика(GIMP)</a></li>
                 <li><a href='vector.html'>Векторная графика</a></li>
                  <li><a href='infografica.html'>Инфографика</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Печатная продукция</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='pechat.html'>Scribus</a></li>
              </ul>
             <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Мультимедийные приложения</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href='#'>Сервисы интернета</a></li>
                 <li><a href='#'>Офисное оборудование</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Презентации</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           </li>
          
        </ul>
     </li>
 <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'>Техническая документация</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'>Текстовый отчет о Моей работе</a>
           </li>
          <li><a href='brif.html'>Бриф на разработку сайта</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Прочее...</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href='kontakti.html'>Контакты/Обо мне</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
    </div> <!-- end of header -->
    
  <div id="tooplate_main">
    
        <div id="home" class="content_top"></div>
        <div class="content_box">
            <div class="content_title content_ct"><h2>Портфолио Андреева Владимира</h2></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image_wrapper image_fl"><img src="images/XXL.jpg" alt="Image 01" /><span></span></div>
            <p><em>Добро пожаловать на мой сайт. Здесь я бы хотел предоставить свои работы во время учебы на 2-ом курсе и практике. Я работал в разнообразных программах, результаты работ моих раюот можете посмотреть на данном сайте.</em></p>
                <p>ЧТОТО</p>
                <div class="cleaner h30"></div>
                <div class="col_w340 float_l">
                    <h3>Программы в которых я работал:</h3>
                    <ul class="tooplate_list">
                        <li>GIMP</li>
                        <li>Scribus</li>
                        <li>SketchUP</li>
                        <li>Notepad++</li>
                        <li>Open Office</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col_w340 float_r">
                    <h3>Разработка сайта</h3>
                    <blockquote>
                    <p>Сайт разработан на основе гипертекстовой разметки HTML5 и CSS3 - на котором я делал стилизацию сайта и его оформление.
Также был использован JavaScript(JS) для программного доступа к объектам приложений.                </blockquote>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="content_bottom content_cb"><a href=http://www.chemk.org class="gototop">Сайт колледжа</a></div>
        </div> 
        
        <div id="aboutus" class="content_top"></div>
        <div class="content_box">
            
    
    <div id="tooplate_footer"> Данная работа была выполнена в рамках квалификационного экзамена по профессии "Оператор ЭВМ".</BR> Андреев В.В.
      <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div>
    
</div> <!-- end of warpper -->
</div> <!-- end of body wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: советовали что-то через @media screen, но как-то криво выходит

Answer (score 1):

Без html сложновато.
Но по факту вам нужно ограничение на ширину убрать у блоков.
Вижу у вас у вропперов `width:800px;`

Comment: Обновил пост...